# How to solve Invalid use of NULL in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am using vba script to calculate(Just addition) and display the values in Excel Userform, but I am getting the error

> Runtime error:94, Invalid use of Null

I tried to change the type to float, but still no improvements.

```
Private Sub submitmobile_Click()
    Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Sheets("Report").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If Sheets("Report").Cells(i, "A").Value = (Me.lst_Added) Or _
          Sheets("Report").Cells(i, "A").Value = Val(Me.lst_Added) Then
            Me.mobileutilize = Sheets("Report").Cells(i, "F").Value
            Me.mobilehours = Sheets("Report").Cells(i, "H").Value
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I expect the output should be displayed in the textboxes mentioned (mobileutilize, mobilehours) with the value as it is in sheet cells

Comment: At which code line does the Error appear?

Comment: Set a breakpoint on that line and run the macro until you reach that line. Hover about the variables in that line. Exactly which one is `NULL`?

Comment: thanks for your reply the below code works @Dominique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming the `lst_Added` is a Listbox.

So before using it, check if something is selected or not. You can do that by

```
If lst_Added.Listindex = -1 Then
    Msgbox "Please select something"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Then use your code as

```
If Sheets("Report").Cells(i, "A").Value = lst_Added.Value....
```

Your code can be written as (**Untested**)

```
Private Sub submitmobile_Click()
    Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long
    Dim lbValue As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    If lst_Added.ListIndex = -1 Then
        MsgBox "Please select something"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    '~~> Get value of the selected item in the listbox
    lbValue = lst_Added.List(lst_Added.ListIndex)

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report")

    With ws
        LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To LastRow
            If .Cells(i, "A").Value = lbValue Or _
               .Cells(i, "A").Value = Val(lbValue) Then
                mobileutilize = .Cells(i, "F").Value
                mobilehours = .Cells(i, "H").Value
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```